# Breaking out of a nested loop in bash

Tags: bash

How do you break out of a nested loop in bash?

Tried `continue` and `break`. `break` worked. But want to learn more.

```
for i in 1 2 3; do 
  if [[ $flag -eq 1 ]]; then
    break
  fi
done
```

How does `break` actually know the loop is nested?
Instead of `break`, can I use `i=4` or something out of range to exit from a loop.

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop, so there is no nested loop in your example.

Comment: Like most other languages, bash tracks the lexical scope of all statements. While interpreting the `if` statement, bash has made a note of the fact that it's part of a loop. That's how the `break` statement knows what to do.

Answer (score 28):

Use `break` followed by a number, to break out of that many levels of nesting. Example:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo
    echo i = $i
    for j in 1 2 3 4 5; do
        echo j = $j
        if [ $j -eq 4 ]; then break; fi
        if [ $j -eq 3 ] && [ $i -eq 4 ]; then break 2; fi
    done
done
```

Result:

```
i = 1
j = 1
j = 2
j = 3
j = 4

i = 2
j = 1
j = 2
j = 3
j = 4

i = 3
j = 1
j = 2
j = 3
j = 4

i = 4
j = 1
j = 2
j = 3
```

Comment: In your example, there are 2 for loops. Do the if loops count for break? The default number for break is 1?

Comment: @hithesh After someone responds to one of your comments, please don't make changes to it that would change the meaning of the response. Anyway, no, `if`s aren't loops, so they don't count, and yes, the default is 1.

Comment: Since the anwer edit queue is full, let's use the comment section. `break --help` should also state relative information. It also worth to mention that a `break` will end all specified loop depth immediately. In other words, specified loops won't pass until their block end but stop their execution practically instantly. The behavior of "break" depends on the Bash version (e.g. "break" will cause the `subshell` to exit if reached it in its parent shell), and more information should be available in "Compatibility" details document: http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/COMPAT